# Applying as a dependent 457 visa subclass of spouse while waiting for tourist visa

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, australia

I have applied for a tourist visa to Australia on the 24th of Jan this year soon after I got married to visit my Husband who is living there under Temporary graduate visa. We thought since the partner applications and all takes a lot of time and we wanted to be together, hence we went for the decision. My tourist visa is still under processing it shows..

Now, on the 27th of Feb this year, my spouse has added my name as his dependent in his 457 subclass sponsorship visa application. So, will that affect my tourist visa application, nullify or cancel it out? Is there a chance of refusal due to this? Because i don't want to wait for the whole period of 8-11 months away from my husband while the 457 is on process and granted. Is there a chance that I will get my tourist visa and visit my husband for 3 months?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you first determine whether you would be eligible for a [bridging visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visi/visi/bridging-visas) should you enter as a tourist, it may be wise to [withdraw your tourist visa application](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/can-i-withdraw-my-visa-application).

Your intention is to join your partner and stay in Australia long-term; a tourist visa is not meant for that. You risk your visa being cancelled or not being admitted, a negative immigration history that could affect other applications, both to Australia and other countries.